# Re-initialize ActiveRecord after rails startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm building a system which allows the user to modify the database.yml contents via an admin frontend interface.

That changes to database.yml obviously don't have any affect until the application is restarted.  Rather than forcing the user (who may not have SSH access to the physical box) to restar the application manually, I'd like a way to force ActiveRecord to reload the config post startup.

Rather than requiring them to restart the server, is there a way to force ActiveRecord to re-initialize after initial startup?

**Rationale**

There are two use cases for this - a) initial setup wizard b) moving from sqlite evaluation database to production supported database.

*Initial Setup Wizard*

After installing our application and starting it for the first time the user will be presented with a setup wizard, which amongst other things, allows the user to choose between the built in evaluation database using sqlite or to specify a production supported database.  They need to specify the database properties.  Rather than asking users to edit `yml` files on the server we wish the present a frontend to do so during initial setup.

*Moving from sqlite evaluation database to production supported database*

If the user opted to go with the built in evaluation database, but alter wants to migrate to a production database they need to update the database settings to reflect this change. Same reasons as above, a front end rather than requiring the user to edit config files is desired, especially since we can validate connectivity, permissions etc from the application rather than the user finding out it didn't work when they try to start the application and they get an activerecord exception.

Comment: Reasons added - appreciate it might not be the "standard" use of a rails application, but that doesn't make it a terrible idea off the cuff. A lot of installed applications function this way.

Comment: If your customers are hosting themselves and/or getting the code for your app, they absolutely should be able to edit a freakin' YAML file. They're still going to have to setup a database, load the schema onto it, and seed the data at bare minimum. If you're hosting them, you shouldn't be relying on them to configure the database, and you probably don't want to give them that sort of access.

Comment: Your assumptions are not correct.  Our users need not load the schema or seed the database - this is handled by our setup program. Please don't assume that just because this is a rails app that our end users are typical rails developers.  They are business consumers who purchase shrink wrapped software, and expect a certain experience.

Comment: Also just because they technically *can* edit a yml file, that doesn't mean we want to force them to. That isn't the user experience we want to create for our customers. Obviously for our Saas offering we handle all of that, and no they can't edit the database configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Rails stack on the next request just as you would if you had access to the server.

```
system("touch #{File.join(Rails.root,'tmp','restart.txt')")
```

Comment: Thanks - but we're not running passenger

Answer (score 1):

Building on @wless1's answer in order to get ERB-like ENV vars (e.g. `<%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>`) working try this:

```
YAML::load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "config/database.yml"))).result)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection config[Rails.env]
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could achieve this with the following:

```
config = YAML::load File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "config/database.yml"))

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection config[Rails.env]
```

You'd have to execute the reconnection code in every rails process you're running for it to be effective. There's a bunch of dangerous things to worry about here though - race conditions when changing the database config, syntax problems in the new database.yml, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with ENV stuff, reads: `"host"=>"<%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>"`